# How to import a module from a different directory and have it look for files in that directory

Tags: python

I'm trying to import a Python module in the directory `/home/kurt/dev/clones/ipercron-utils/tester`. This directory contains a `tester.py` and a `config.yml` file. The `tester.py` includes the (leading) line

```
config = yaml.safe_load(open("config.yml"))
```

Now, from another directory, I try to import it like so:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, "/home/kurt/dev/clones/ipercron-utils/tester")
import tester
```

However, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/kurt/dev/clones/ipercron-compose/controller/controller_debug2.py", line 9, in <module>
    import tester
  File "/home/kurt/dev/clones/ipercron-utils/tester/tester.py", line 28, in <module>
    config = yaml.safe_load(open("config.yml"))
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'config.yml'
```

As I understand it, Python is looking for the `config.yml` file in the current directory (`/home/kurt/dev/clones/ipercron-compose/controller`) whereas I want it to look in the directory the module was imported from (`/home/kurt/dev/clones/ipercron-utils/tester`). Is there any way to specify this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`__file__` always contains the current module filepath (here `/home/kurt/dev/clones/ipercron-utils/tester/tester.py`).

Just perform a `dirname` on it => you have the path which contains your `yml` configuration file.

code it like this in your `tester.py` module (`import os` if not already done):

```
module_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
config = yaml.safe_load(open(os.path.join(module_dir,"config.yml")))
```

side note: `__file__` doesn't work on the main file when the code is "compiled" using py2exe. In that case you have to do:

```
module_dir = os.path.dirname(sys.executable)
```